# Select specific columns to read from PostgreSQL based on python list

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I have two lists : one contains the column names of *categorical variables* and the other numeric as shown below.

```
cat_cols = ['stat','zip','turned_off','turned_on']
num_cols = ['acu_m1','acu_cnt_m1','acu_cnt_m2','acu_wifi_m2']
```

These are the columns names in a table in Redshift.

I want to pass these as a parameter to pull only numeric columns from a table in **Redshift(PostgreSql)**,write that into a `csv` and close the `csv`.

Next I want to pull only `cat_cols` and open the `csv` and then append to it and close it.

my query so far:

```
#1.Pull num data:
seg = ['seg1','seg2']
sql_data = str(""" SELECT {num_cols} """ + """FROM public.""" + str(seg) + """ order by random() limit 50000 ;""")
df_data = pd.read_sql(sql_data, cnxn)

# Write to csv.
df_data.to_csv("df_sample.csv",index = False)

#2.Pull cat data:
sql_data = str(""" SELECT {cat_cols} """ + """FROM public.""" + str(seg) + """ order by random() limit 50000 ;""")
df_data = pd.read_sql(sql_data, cnxn)
# Append to df_seg.csv and close the connection to csv.
with open("df_sample.csv",'rw'):
    ## Append to the csv ##
```

This is the first time I am trying to do selective querying based on python lists and hence stuck on how to pass the list as column names to select from table.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, to make a query in a string representation, in your case will be better to use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) method, or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (required python 3.6+).

Example for the your case, only with built-in `format` function.

```
seg = ['seg1', 'seg2']
num_cols = ['acu_m1','acu_cnt_m1','acu_cnt_m2','acu_wifi_m2']

query = """
SELECT {} FROM public.{} order by random() limit 50000;
""".format(', '.join(num_cols), seg)
print(query)
```

If you want use only one item from the `seg` array, use `seg[0]` or `seg[1]` in `format` function.

I hope this will help you!